# excel formula copying value with 0 string

Tags: excel, vba

i have a cell A, B, and C.

A=16

B=01

C=0001

my question is i want a value of the cell D is like this D = 16-01-0001.

Note cell D is dynamic sometimes in cell D the value is 0021 or 0321 . .

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the strings from the cells with the "-" text string. The concatenation operator is the ampersand sign `&`

```
Sub test()

Range("D1") = Range("A1") & "-" & Range("B1") & "-" & Range("C1")

End Sub
```

Or use a formula instead of VBA:

```
=A1&"-"&B1&"-"&C1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Range("D1").Value = Range("A1").Value - Range("B1").Value - Range("C1").Value
```

Note: Here, the values within the brackets refer to the cells the numbers are located in, these are just examples.

Comment: Did you test that? `-` is the subtraction operator and your statement returns the number `14` to the cell.

Comment: I do believe that I have misunderstood the question, I apologise. I thought that was the purpose of the question